# How to calculate coefficient of variation for extremely small numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate squared coefficient of variation i.e.:

[image]

For sample X, where

[image]

**My work so far**

I cannot simply take exponent of ln(X) because those numbers are to small and will be treated as 0. I read on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation) that we can use estimation of form (when sample is big):

[image]

However, when I'm using this formula, I obtain very unstable result:

```
vec = np.array([-750.1729, -735.0251])
np.exp(np.var(vec)) - 1
8.1818556596351e+24
```

Is there any opportunity to have result more accurate? Or it has to be this way, because variance is very big with respect to mean?

Comment: "when sample is big": I see a sample size of 2, which is not what they call "big", usually.

Comment: Its just an example. I had exactly same results for sample with size bigger than 100. For purposes of example in my opinion two observation sample is okay

Comment: So your example with the estimation does not make sense.

Comment: Anyway, the coefficient of variation is an homogeneous quantity, so you can shift the logarithms arbitrarily to rescale the samples.

Comment: So instead of considering log(X) you would consider log(X) + 700 because variance stays the same?

Comment: Yep, that's it.